# Indexing PDF with Sunspot Solr issue?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

We want index rich documents(PDF). We are facing some issues:

Console log

```
301836 [qtp2064029636-12] INFO  org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor  – [pdf] webapp=/solr path=/update/extract params={literal.created_at_d=2014-10-06T09:37:25Z&fmap.content=document_attachment_attachment&literal.id_i=17&literal.file_name_text=vij&literal.id=Attachment+17&literal.type=Attachment&literal.type=ActiveRecord::Base&literal.updated_at_d=2014-10-06T09:37:25Z&literal.class_name=Attachment&wt=ruby} {} 0 333
```

Index in console

```
Backtrace: /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot-691b42e73bea/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot-691b42e73bea/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in `send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot_cell-0c0b7f980b8c/lib/sunspot/rich_document.rb:41:in `add'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot_cell-0c0b7f980b8c/lib/sunspot_cell/indexer.rb:25:in `block in add_documents'
/home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot_cell-0c0b7f980b8c/lib/sunspot_cell/indexer.rb:24:in `each'
    from /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:283:in `adapt_response'
    from /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:190:in `execute'
    from /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/rsolr-1.0.10/lib/rsolr/client.rb:176:in `send_and_receive'
    from /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/bundler/gems/sunspot-691b42e73bea/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in `block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
    from /home/kannan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@pdf_atch/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar and found this link: See if it is useful for you:
https://cbpowell.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/indexing-rich-documents-with-rails-sunspot-solr-sunspot-cell-and-carrierwave-cookbook-style/

Comment: same problem for that link type also.

Comment: I am also facing same problem..Did somebody figured out?